# Angular material dialog doesnt deselect button when closing

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a button, which when is clicked opens a new material dialog, in the dialog component i implemented an on close method which calls dialog reference .close(), it all works fine with one exception, if instead of closing the dialog by pressing cancel button, or by clicking outside the dialog, i close it by pressing the escape button, the dialog closes, but the button which i clicked in the first place to open the dialog remains selected, until i click something from the page. Is there any way to deselect the button without increasing the coupling of the components?

```
//this function gets triggered when i press the button to open a new modal
openModal() {
    const dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ModalComponent> =
      this.matDialog.open(ModalComponent);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((data: any) => {
      ...some operations
    });
  }
```

and in the modal component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dialogRef.keydownEvents().subscribe(event => {
      if (event.key === "Escape") {
        this.cancel();
      }
    });

    this.dialogRef.backdropClick().subscribe(event => {
      this.cancel();
    });
  }

cancel() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
```

Comment: Show us the code to understand more.

Comment: @DA , i added the code snippet

Comment: This could be a focus issue, there is a section in the angular material documentation that talks about this. Try changing to this.matDialog.open(ModalComponent, {restoreFocus: false}); and see if it works

Comment: @caslawter , it worked, thank you a lot!!